# Dataproc initialization script error pip command not found error when using multiple initialization scripts

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Following is the command i have used to create the dataproc cluster. There are two initialization scripts here. (1) `jupyter.sh` (2) `my_initialize.sh`

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create dproc \
    --subnet default --zone us-west1-a --project myproject \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh,gs://mydataproc/my_initialize.sh \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-8 --master-boot-disk-size 40 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-8 --worker-boot-disk-size 40 --num-workers 4
```

Following is in my_initialize.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

When we install jupyter.sh, i believe pip is already installed.

For some reason cluster creation is failed with the error as 
line 2: pip command not found.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue where the init action is not seeing changes to the environment from previous init actions. We will be rolling out a fix for this in next few weeks so sourcing `profile.d` should not be necessary after that. This will be announced in [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes).

In the mean time (as @Karthik Palaniappan mentions, just use pip by its full path `/opt/conda/bin/pip`.

Finally, on Dataproc `1.3` image you can use Anaconda+Jupyter [Optional Components](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/optional-components). Using components over init actions will cut down on overall cluster boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is because neither `pip` nor anything else in `/opt/conda/bin/` are in `$PATH` for your second init action. In fact, they don't end up on the path for the `root` user, even if you run `sudo su root`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/246.

If you're interested in fixing that issue, I'd be happy to accept a PR. Just as a starting point:`bootstrap-conda.sh` sets up `/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/conda/bootstrap-conda.sh#L136).

And other scripts [source that file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/conda/install-conda-env.sh#L6) explicitly.

Unless there's a simple way to change `$PATH` systemwide, I think your best bet is to explicitly source `/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` as well.

Alternatively, run `pip` with its absolute path, e.g. `/opt/conda/bin/pip install ...`.